# If functions converge a.e. and their integrals converge, does convergence in $L^1$ follow?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I was wondering if $f_n, f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are s.t. $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e. and $\int f_n\rightarrow \int f$ where integrals are Lebesgue Integrals, is there any Theorem or any approach that will let me conclude $\int |f_n-f|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: There are conditions that will make this true. Check out Vitale's convergence theorem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f_n,f\geq 0$ then you can consider the sequence $$g_n=\min(f_n,f)=\frac{1}{2}(f_n+f-|f_n-f|)$$ which is bounded by $f$ and and converges pointwise a.e. to $f$. Then use the dominated convergence to obtain the claim.

Generally, if you allow $f_n,f$ to attain values in $\mathbb R$,  the claim is not true. Consider the functions $f_n= n \chi_{[0,1/n]}-n\chi_{[1/n,2/n]}$. These converge to $0$ a.e. and 
$$\int f_n= n\cdot (1/n)- n\cdot (1/n)=0$$
However, $|f_n|= n \chi_{[0,2/n]}$ and $\int |f_n|= n\cdot (2/n)=2$ which does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Yes, thanks I'll delete my comment!